# Center the caption relative to the graph, not relative to the entire text block

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

Hey so my question this time is about the caption of the figure. In my case it appears to be centered on the page when i compile it but i want it to be centered on top of my figure at the Left side of the page. so how do i center it relative to the figure i'm using?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Leistungskennlinie}
\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, so instead of using `Din_A3_Diagramm_NeY_ReX`, consider `example-image` as suggested in [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Aside: Instead of `\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}`, try `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`. :-)

Comment: Centering the caption over the image doesn't really make sense; you may want left flush captions, if you have left flush images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to center-set the caption on the (non-centered) graph, I suggest you encase both the caption and the graph in a `minipage`:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth} % choose a suitable width
\caption{Leistungskennlinie}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} % <--- use "width=...", not "scale=..."
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

That way, the caption text will never be wider than the minipage (and the graph).

A full MWE and screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
%% I've slimmed the preamble to the bare minimum...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth} % choose a suitable width
\caption{Leistungskennlinie}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} % <--- use "width=...", not "scale=..."
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a VERY narrow image (from the MWE) then you need to lose the hanging indentation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\sbox0{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{example-image}}% get width
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
\caption{Leistungskennlinie}
\usebox0
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]